# How do you serialize a font with ProtoBuf.Net?

Tags: c#-4.0, fonts, protobuf-net

I need to serialize a font into a class using ProtoBuf.Net
How would one go about accomplishing this?

I know how ProtoBuf works but I don't think:

```
[ProtoContract()]
public class ClassWithFont{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Font ProtoFont{ get; set; }
}
```

would work.

Comment: Can you not just serialize the *name* (etc) of the font?

Comment: That's kind of the solution I came up with. Serialize the Font.FontFamily.Name and the Font.Style (since I don't care about the size). Then when I set it, Font = new Font(ProtoFont, 12, ProtoStyle). It's... about as good as it gets, I guess.